Why does this C code not print 'a' in output?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){
   char x[9]="helloabc";
   x[8]='\0';
   int a=2,b=3;
   strcpy(&x[2],&x[4]);
   for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
       printf("%c",x[i]);
   }
}

Almost all compilers output "heocbc\0c". Why does this C code not print 'a' in output?

strcpy behaviour is undefined for overlapping strings

Welcome to SO. Your use of strcpy is illegal. You mustn't use it to copy overlapping areas. If you do it, that is causing undefined behaviour. Also, x[8]='\0'; is useless. A string literal already contains the nul-terminator and your array is large enough to hold it, too.

General note regarding "Almost all compilers..." If the behaviour depends on the compiler you use, chances are high that you invoke undefined behaviour in your code. (Or at least implementation defined behaviour.)

Use memmove(&a[2], &a[4], strlen(&a[4]) + 1); — memmove() handles overlapping data correctly.

In this line:
strcpy(&x[2],&x[4]);

The source and destination strings overlap.
From strcpy documentation:

The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap.

With UB (undefined behavior) anything can happen.
This means there is no point rationalazing what happens with this or other compiler.
As @JonathanLeffler commented above, you can use memmove, which supports overlapping data:
memmove(&x[2], &x[4], strlen(&x[4]) + 1);

With it the output should be:
heoabc␀c         // ␀ represents a NUL

See Live demo (Godbolt).
